# differential equation contain sin(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question

I would like to know how to work out such differential equation, by hand without using matlab:

$x''= A + B \sin(x)$
then $x = ?$
A,B are parameters

Comment: Your problem statement is incoherent. What is the independent variable ? What is the dependent variable ? One of $x, y, t$ is extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

Let the differential equation:
$$x''=A+B\sin x$$
Multiply both sides by $x'$ to make them total differentials:
$$x'x''=(A+B\sin x)x'$$
Integrate:
$$\frac12x'^2=Ax-B\cos x+C$$
The next step is to integrate the separable equation:
$$\frac{x'}{\sqrt{2(Ax-B\cos x+C)}}=1$$
At this stage you are blocked as the left hand side cannot be integrated analytically.

UPDATE:

The OP changed the LHS from $x''$ to $y''$ after the fact, which makes a huge difference!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming when you write "x''(2nd order)" you mean "a function of $x$ that is differentiated twice".  I've called this function "$f$" below.  If you do not mean that then a little clarification might help.

Integrate both sides once, getting
$$ f'(x) = A x - B x \cos x + B \sin x + C $$
and integrate again, getting
$$ f(x) = \frac{A x^2}{2} - B x \sin x - 2 B \cos x + C x + D $$

$A$ and $B$ are your given parameters.  $C$ and $F$ are constants of integration that can usually be found using initial or boundary conditions.